# The CSS animated loader work correctly only once in IE 11

Tags: html, css, animation, internet-explorer-11

The CSS loader doesn't work sometimes in IE 11. When the page is loaded for the first time, everything is OK. But after the first correct one, the loader is displayed incorrectly, and only the central stick changes it's size. Seems like `:before` and `:after` pieces don't work properly. How can I fix it for IE 11? It works fine for Chrome, for example.

```
.loader {
    background: #1C5685;
    position: relative;
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: 250px auto;
    color: #1C5685;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before {
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #1C5685;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1.5em;
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #1C5685;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 1.5em;
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

@keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

#loadingDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```css
.loader {
   background: #1C5685;
   position: relative;
   width: 0.8em;
   height: 4em;
   margin: 250px auto;
   color: #1C5685;
   text-indent: -9999em;
   font-size: 11px;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
   animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before {
   width: 0.8em;
   height: 4em;
   background: #1C5685;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -1.5em;
   -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
   animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
   width: 0.8em;
   height: 4em;
   background: #1C5685;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 1.5em;
   -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
   animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
   0%,
   80%,
   100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0;
      height: 4em;
   }
   40% {
      box-shadow: 0 -2em;
      height: 5em;
   }
}

@keyframes load1 {
   0%,
   80%,
   100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0;
      height: 4em;
   }
   40% {
      box-shadow: 0 -2em;
      height: 5em;
   }
}

#loadingDiv {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   opacity: 0.7;
   z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="loadingDiv">
   <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

UPD: 
[It was to pulse like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPt0t.png)

[But it did it like this (only middle stick pulsed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJaht.png)

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not reproduce your issue successfully. I've tested your working demo, and it works well any time when I open the page in IE. You could see the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXtvH.gif Could you please show your issue with a screenshot so I could understand clearly?

Comment: Updated with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was found by myself - to replace the unproperly working in IE ":before" and ":after" pseudo-elements with REAL elements, to update their animation delays and to put them together (they are not displayed by default and become visible on loadings):

```
<!-- 3 loadingDiv's with loaders inside: 1 div for each of 3 animated sticks of loader -->
<div style="display:none" id="loadingDiv1">
    <div class="loader1" >Loading...</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="loadingDiv2">
    <div class="loader2" >Loading...</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="loadingDiv3">
    <div class="loader3" >Loading...</div>
</div>

.loader1,
.loader2,
.loader3 {
    background: #1C5685;
    position: relative;
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: 250px auto;
    color: #1C5685;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
/* .loader3 has 0 delay */

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}
@keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}
#loadingDiv1,
#loadingDiv2,
#loadingDiv3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 3;
}
#loadingDiv1 {
    left: -1em;
    background-color: white;
}
#loadingDiv2 {
    left: 0;
}
#loadingDiv3 {
    left: 1em;
}
```